# Airflow: Create DAG from a separate file

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In airflow, I'm trying to make a function that is dedicated to generate DAGs in a file:

```
dynamic_dags.py:

def generate_dag(name):
    with DAG(
        dag_id=f'dag_{name}',
        default_args=args,
        start_date=days_ago(2),
        schedule_interval='5 5 * * *',
        tags=['Test'],
        catchup=False
    ) as dag:
        dummy_task=DummyOperator(
            task_id="dynamic_dummy_task",
            dag=dag
        )
    return dag
```

Then in another file I'm trying to import the dags from a separate file:

```
load_dags.py:

from dynamic_dag import generate_dag
globals()["Dynamic_DAG_A"] = generate_dag('A')
```

However, the dags are not shown up on web UI.
But if I do them in a single file as below code, it will work:

```
def generate_dag(name):
    with DAG(
        dag_id=f'dag_{name}',
        default_args=args,
        start_date=days_ago(2),
        schedule_interval='5 5 * * *',
        tags=['Test'],
        catchup=False
    ) as dag:
        dummy_task=DummyOperator(
            task_id="dynamic_dummy_task",
            dag=dag
        )
    return dag

globals()["Dynamic_DAG_A"] = generate_dag('A')
```

I'm wondering why doing it in two separate files doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are using Airflow 1.10, then the DAG files should contain `DAG` and airlfow:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/concepts.html?highlight=airflowignore#dags

> When searching for DAGs, Airflow only considers python files that contain the strings “airflow” and “DAG” by default. To consider all python files instead, disable the DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE configuration flag.

In Airflow 2 it's been changed (slightly - dag is case-insensitive):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/concepts/dags.html

> When searching for DAGs inside the DAG_FOLDER, Airflow only considers Python files that contain the strings airflow and dag (case-insensitively) as an optimization.
> To consider all Python files instead, disable the DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE configuration flag.

I think you simply miss 'airflow' in your `load_dags.py`. You can add it wherever - including comments.